# Cosa significa "smaltire i rifiuti"?

Tags: meaning

Ho trovato l'espressione "smaltire i rifiuti" in un esercizio d'italiano. Si tratta di un'espressione nuova per me, quindi ho consultato alcuni dizionari per cercarne di chiarirne il significato. Comunque, non riesco a capire se si tratta di portare via i rifiuti o di farli sparire per mezzo del riciclaggio, per esempio. Potreste spiegarmi cosa significa esattamente "smaltire i rifiuti"?

Comment: ***Smaltimento dei rifiuti***: trattamento dei rifiuti, spec. urbani e industriali, mediante particolari procedimenti che ne consentono l'eliminazione o il riciclaggio http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/S/smaltimento.php

Comment: Contrariamente a quanto scrive kos, lo 'smaltimento' è l'ultima delle possibili opzioni, almeno in Italia, per la gestione dei rifiuti. Le opzioni, in ordine gerarchico, sono infatti queste:

a) prevenzione;
b) preparazione per il riutilizzo;
c) riciclaggio;
d) recupero di altro tipo, per esempio il recupero di energia;
**e) smaltimento**.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider: Non capisco cosa vuoi dire.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider dice che dovremmo preferire allo smaltimento gli altri passi: 
1. Prima di tutto è meglio evitare di produrre rifiuti; 2. Se devono essere prodotti, dovrebbero essere riutilizzabili; 3. Se non possono essere riutilizzabili, dovrebbero essere riciclabili; 4. Se non sono riciclabili, devono essere impiegati in qualche altro modo (es. inceneriti per la produzione di energia); 5. Se non si può fare altrimenti, sono smaltiti nelle discariche.

Comment: @laureapresa: Ma allora "smaltire i rifiuti" verrebbe inteso come portare via i rifiuti dalle città per scaricarli altrove e non come il loro riciclaggio o la loro trasformazione per il riutilizzo?

Comment: @Charo Esatto, è proprio così, ancorché nel parlato comune tali differenze—sebbene nelle scuole italiane insegnino educazione ambientale—siano ancora in una fase embrionale. Le risposta di kos, che pur sbagliata becca 7 voti, è una dimostrazione di ciò.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider La domanda è "Cosa significa smaltire i rifiuti? Portarli via o farli sparire ad esempio attraverso il riciclaggio?". Mi spieghi per lo scopo della domanda dov'è che è necessario nell'ambito della risposta citare le "alternative" al riciclaggio in ordine "gerarchico"?

Comment: @ElberichSchneider: Capisco cosa vuoi dire perché qualche brano della Wikipedia sembra suggerire appunto questo. Ma non credo che si possa affermare che l'Enciclopedia Treccani sia sbagliata.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il significato di "smaltire" in generale è da considerarsi simile al significato di "eliminare / trasformare", e quindi in questo caso uno può ridurlo tranquillamente alla sola "eliminazione / trasformazione dei rifiuti" in senso stretto (nel caso della domanda quindi al solo processo di riciclaggio) senza dire niente di sbagliato; citando l'[Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/rifiuto/#smaltimentodeirifiuti-1):

> 3. Smaltimento dei rifiuti
>
> [...] Prescindendo dai sistemi che hanno solo un valore storico e documentario, le principali tecniche di smaltimento sono: la discarica controllata (discarica), l’incenerimento mediante l’uso di inceneritori attrezzati con impianti di controllo e purificazione dei fumi emessi, il compostaggio e il riciclaggio . [...]

Comunque generalmente nell'uso comune "smaltire i rifiuti" si riferisce per estensione, molto genericamente e più largamente, all'intero processo di trattamento dei rifiuti; molto genericamente perché oltre ad essere "smaltire" già di per se un verbo piuttosto generico (basta dare un'occhiata al numero e alla variegatura di tutte le accezioni riportate dal [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/smaltire/), che tuttavia ricordano tutte almeno concettualmente l'accezione menzionata) l'intero processo include nello specifico varie fasi (raccolta, trasporto, ...) seguite da varie possibili procedure di trattamento (incenerimento, riciclaggio, stoccaggio, ...), che non sono sempre le stesse per ogni generico "rifiuto".

---

A supporto di questo, inoltre, la TARSU (TAssa per lo smaltimento dei Rifiuti Solidi Urbani, una tassa che avevamo qui in Italia ora sostituita dalla TARI), che si riferiva nell'acronimo stesso allo "smaltimento dei rifiuti", includeva in realtà nell'importo pagato anche per esempio il servizio di raccolta e il servizio di trasporto; citando [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tassa_per_lo_smaltimento_dei_rifiuti_solidi_urbani):

> L'applicazione è demandata ai comuni, sulla base del costo totale del servizio di raccolta e successivo smaltimento dei rifiuti usando come parametro la superficie dei locali di abitazione e di attività dove possono avere origine rifiuti di varia natura.

Comment: L'articolo della Wikipedia sembra suggerire però che, nel senso più stretto, lo "smaltimento dei rifiuti" non comprende il riciclaggio.

Comment: @Charo Mmmh si ma suggerisce male: Wikipedia l'ho citata solo perché mi faceva comodo per pseudo-dimostrare che con la TARSU si pagava sia la raccolta che il trasporto che lo smaltimento. Questo è l'articolo dell'Enciclopedia Treccani su rifiuto: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/rifiuto/#smaltimentodeirifiuti-1. Domattina aggiungo anche le informazioni contenute qui

Comment: @Charo Ho aggiunto l'estratto rilevante che asserisce che "smaltimento dei rifiuti" si riferisce al processo vero e proprio, come potrebbe essere il riciclaggio al pari di qualsiasi altra procedura (il che implica che nonostante Wikipedia dica il contrario il riciclaggio è una parte dello "smaltimento dei rifiuti", e che giustifica il primo paragrafo nel quale ho detto che si può ridurre il significato generico di "smaltimento dei rifiuti" al solo processo, come il riciclaggio, vero e proprio)