# "Per mezzo di" è l'espressione più adatta?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

In [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5933) ho scritto

> non riesco a capire se si tratta di portare via i rifiuti o di farli sparire *per mezzo del* riciclaggio, per esempio

ma non ero sicura se "per mezzo di" fosse l'espressione più adatta in questo contesto. Che ne pensate? Potreste propormi preposizioni o locuzioni preposizionali alternative a "per mezzo di"?

Comment: Come ha detto Josh61 "per mezzo del" è perfettamente corretto, e come Josh61 ha già proposto anch'io forse avrei scelto "tramite" / "tramite il"; comunque continuando a scegliere tra espressioni contenenti "mezzo" avresti potuto usare "a mezzo", che è idiomatico e che sarebbe suonato leggermente meglio: "non riesco a capire se si tratta di portare via i rifiuti o di farli sparire a mezzo riciclaggio"

Comment: Personalmente (sempre questione di orecchio e gusti), considero più o meno equivalenti “per mezzo di” e “tramite”, mentre “a mezzo” mi suona un po' più legnoso, forse per l'assenza della preposizione (e magari anche perché a una lettura rapida si potrebbe confondere con l'aggettivo “mezzo”, come se si parlasse di un riciclaggio a metà).

Comment: @kos: Interessante: non conoscevo quest'espressione, "a mezzo".

Comment: Forse perchè principalmente è usato in contesti lavorativi o più formali (dove è idiomatico, mi capita di leggerlo molto spesso), ad esempio comprando un oggetto online potresti facilmente leggere "Consegna a mezzo corriere espresso entro 2 giorni lavorativi"

Comment: Alcuno esempi si possono vedere qui: ***a mezzo di*** , ***per mezzo di***, ***tramite***: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+mezzo+di%2Cper+mezzo+di%2C+tramite&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20mezzo%20di%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cper%20mezzo%20di%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctramite%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Potresti dire:

...o farli sparire (eliminarli) riciclandoli.

...o farli sparire (eliminarli) ***[tramite](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tramite/)*** il riciclaggio.

> - ( prep.) per mezzo di, attraverso : *tramite il competente ufficio; gli diede sue notizie tramite un amico.* (Treccani.it)

- La locuzione '*per mezzo del*' è comunque corretta.

Answer (score -1):

Invece di "o di farli sparire per mezzo del riciclaggio", (in effetti non spariscono) suggerirei "o di disporne col riciclaggio". Se fosse il Comune a parlare (o un ente incaricato dal Comune), potrebbe dire "o di disporne  riciclandoli".

Comment: Attento, alsa, ti stai confondendo con il verbo inglese *to dispose (of)*. In italiano “disporre” non ha quel senso.

Comment: DaG. Secondo il Patto internazionale sui diritti economici, sociali e culturali (entrata in vigore : 23 marzo 1976), "... Per raggiungere i loro fini, tutti i popoli possono disporre liberamente delle proprie ricchezze e delle proprie risorse ..." . Se possiamo "disporre" delle nostre risorse, come è possibile che non possiamo "disporre" della nostra spazzatura? In Toscana certamente si può. Ma grazie (sinceramente) per il suggerimento di non confondermi con l'inglese: di quello ho certamente bisogno.

Comment: ricordavo solo che in italiano l'uso intransitivo di “disporre (di qualcosa)” significa “avere il diritto di servirsi (di quella cosa)” (“disporre di un ingente patrimonio”; “l’ente non dispone dei fondi necessarî”, esempi presi dal Treccani), mentre non ha il senso inglese di “sbarazzarsi, eliminare”.